# Потребление памяти при создании новых объектов в цикле

Tags: php

При создании нового объекта выделяется новая память?

У меня скрипт, который в цикле создаёт новый объект. Это очень плохо?

```
foreach ($notes as $value) {
   $object = new obj();
}
```

При создании нового объекта метод получает контент с помощью `file_get_contents`.

Одним словом, это вытащено из личного класса шаблонизатора.

Comment: @D-sideисправил, не знал, что в php есть объекты.

Comment: Ну, вы приводите в пример код на PHP, а ответ хоть и одинаков, его детали сильно зависят от того, о каком языке речь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете проверить сколько памяти используется

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();

foreach ($notes as $value) {
   $object = new obj();
   echo (memory_get_usage() - $startMemory) . ' bytes' . PHP_EOL;
}

// итого
echo (memory_get_usage() - $startMemory) . ' bytes' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю сколько памяти выделяется для этого.

Comment: Подскажите, можно ли через php узнать, сколько памяти выделяет хостинг?

Comment: Можно. Выполните функцию  `phpinfo();` и найдите параметр `memory_limit`

Answer (score 3):

> При создании нового объекта выделяется новая память?

да, обычно выделяется память. Другое дело, что внутри интерпретатора может происходить оптимизация и переиспользоваться память от старого, только что удаленного объекта.

> У меня скрипт, который в цикле создаёт новый объект. Это очень плохо?

Если создается десяток-другой объектов, то ничего страшного. Хотя с другой стороны, внутри этих объектов может выделятся память на сотни мегабайт, а вот это уже другое дело. Но плохо это или нет - зависит от задачи.

На сколько я помню, старый php удалял память только после того, как скрипт завершал свою работу. А память под один запуск скрипта лимитирована. Если Ваш скрипт запросит слишком много памяти - его прибьет вебсервер.

Comment: Оба ответа являются правильными, но про `memory_get_usage();` не знал, поэтому выбрал решённым ответ первый. Надеюсь не в обиду. Спасибо всем, очень помогли.